# PHP Query vs. JSON - Video Gallery Function

Tags: php, json, video, gallery

I am using a HTML5 Video Gallery that utilizes embedded YouTube videos. The gallery was working fine until last week.  I am using the gallery with the video list being populated by PHP query and echo.

Gallery link: http://codecanyon.net/item/responsive-video-gallery-html5-youtube-vimeo/2918602

As of last week the gallery is buggy/hangs and will not load all the videos every time the page is refreshed.  When I use the gallery with just hard code youtube video list and not the PHP query and echo the gallery works fine.  It seems like the problem is directly related to the PHP query.

I am guessing that youtube changed the API or something.  Nothing appears to have changed on my side of the code.

My questions is, do you think using JSON to populate my gallery video list will fix the problem as the code works fine with hard code?

Thanks for you input!

Jason

Comment: Not enough information given.

Comment: Have you looked at the PHP output in the browser source and compared that to working pages?  I don't see what PHP would have to do with it unless your data is incorrect or has some bad character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

After a trouble shooting I discovered that the problem was due to one of the Youtube videos in my list within my data base was switched to no longer embeddable.  This video combined with the query sort by RAND was causing the inconsistent bugginess knocking down the entire gallery function.